# Negative numbers with both parentheses and dash in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have numbers in a large Excel sheet. The negative numbers are displayed as strings such as (-101.10) corresponding to -101.10. The positive numbers are displayed as usual, such as 101.10.

The problem is, Excel doesn't recognize the combination of both parentheses and the negative symbol.

How can I reformat these negative numbers so that Excel understands?

Comment: Assuming those in Parenthesis are your negative numbers, and they also have the dash, then why not simply find/replace all open and closed parenthesis with nothing?

Comment: @Isolated Can you describe a technique that will change `(-number)` to `-number` but not modify parentheses in other contexts?

Comment: @Scott I envision a column with his/her values, and one would simply need to replace the open and closed paren with nothing. As long as it's not messing up any formulas or anything else in that column, then it seems like an easy edit. Jase still needs to format the column as number if all/some of the cells are text.

Comment: @isolated Your suggestion works. Just replace (-number) to -number and then typecast the column into the Number datatype.

Comment: After the Find/Replace you could give it a custom number format of `#,##0.00;(-#,##0.00)` to put the brackets back while keeping them as numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I’ll assume that you know where the (possibly malformed) numbers are. 
For example, they might all be in Columns `A` and `B`,
having been imported from some external source,
while other columns have formulas, text, or numbers that you have entered.

Pick some area of the workbook that is the same size and shape. 
In the example above,
you would need to pick two columns that aren’t being used for anything else. 
You could use Columns `G` and `H`, or `X` and `Y`,
or you could go to another sheet. 
Assuming that your data are in `A` and `B`, and `G` and `H` are available,
enter the following in Cell `G1`:

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(A1,2)="(-",RIGHT(A1,1)=")"), IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)), "ERROR: "&A1), A1)
```

Drag/fill right to Column `H` and down to cover all your data. 
Then copy and paste values back into Columns `A` and `B`.

Note that this will change `(-number)`
to `-number`,
but not affect parentheses in any other context.